# sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError after Inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

I'm using `sqlacodegen` for reflecting a bunch of tables from my database.
And i'm getting the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'Employee' and 'Sales'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.

Here's a simplified version of my tables.
I read in the documentation that I should use the `foreign_keys` parameter to resolve ambiguity between foreign key targets. Although, I think this problem is because of the inheritance. Could someone help me understand what is going on.

```
# coding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Employee'

    EmployeeId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Sales(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'Sales'

    EmployeeID = Column(ForeignKey('Employee.EmployeeId'), primary_key=True)
    OldemployeeID = Column(ForeignKey('Employee.EmployeeId'))
    employee = relationship('Employee', foreign_keys=[EmployeeID])
    old_employee = relationship("Employee", foreign_keys=[OldemployeeID])
```

Comment: Be sure to specify type (not just Column(Foreign..., but Column(Integer,Foreign....). I've never seen it done without it, not sure if that's the issue here though. I've never done table inheritance.

Comment: What type of inheritance do you want to do? It appears you haven't configured your classes for inheritance.

Comment: I didn't actually do the inheritance myself. This is how some of my tables turn out when i run `sqlacodegen` on my database.

Comment: Well, code generation tools are not perfect. If you don't want inheritance then don't use inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

When your tables have multiple possible paths to inherit between them (`Sales.EmployeeID` or `Sales.OldEmployeeID`), SqlAlchemy doesn't know which one to use and you'll need to tell it the path explicitly, by using `inherit_condition`. For instance to inherit by `EmployeeID`:

```
class Sales(Employee):
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = { "inherit_condition": EmployeeID == Employee.EmployeeId }
```

For the sake of example, you could also inherit by `OldEmployeeID`, by entering `OldEmployeeID == Employee.EmployeeId` - this would mean that both your `Sales` primary key and the `Employee` primary key are allowed to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Just use backref and use Integer on both EmployeeID and OldemployeeID. Otherwise you will get an another error.

```
class Sales(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'Sales'

    EmployeeID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Employee.EmployeeId'), primary_key=True)
    OldemployeeID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Employee.EmployeeId'))
    employee = relationship('Employee', foreign_keys=[EmployeeID], backref='Employee')
    old_employee = relationship("Employee", foreign_keys=[OldemployeeID], backref='Employee')
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same `AmbiguousForeignKeysError`. It occurs when I run the same file where I have defined these two classes.